# numerical solving nonlocal drift-diffusion equation mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically solve the following system:

Let $f:=f(x,t):[0,100]\times \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ solve

$\partial_t f(x,t) + u(x,t)\partial_x f(x,t) = (\partial_x^2 - \frac{1}{x} \partial_x ) f(x,t)$

where $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \frac{f^2(y,t)}{y} d y$

and where initial data is given at $t=0$ to be

$f(x,0)= \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} e^{-x^2}$

and the boundary conditions are Dirichlet $f(0,t)= f(100,t)=0$.

When I tried very naively to code this into mathematica, it simply said that delay equations are not yet supported.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can give specific advice.